# HTML only Marquee animation using inline css only and @keyframes

Tags: html, css, css-animations, inline-styles

I'm using an email platform (Listrak) that **only allows inline CSS** in the email-design.

I made a simple scrolling marquee using inline css.

But now I'm stuck on where to put the @keyframes css?

I can't use  tags. Everything has to be inline css.

```css
@keyframes marquee {
  0% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    left: -336px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div style="display:flex;
  width:600px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: auto;
  background-color:#1892a0;">

  <div style="display:flex;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    white-space: nowrap;
    top: 10px;
    left: 100%;
    justify-content:round;
    font-family: 'TriviaSlabBook', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:32px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:white;
    animation: marquee 3s linear infinite;">

    <span>SPRING BOGO SALE! &nbsp;</span>
    <span>SPRING BOGO SALE! &nbsp;</span>
    <span>SPRING BOGO SALE! &nbsp;</span>
    <span>SPRING BOGO SALE! &nbsp;</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you cannot inline a keyframes. Use a GIF image for animation inside email

Comment: Gifs are not smooth. needs to be CSS.

Comment: you cannot and even if you can it will never work as you want. CSS in email is very limited

Comment: You might try the old and deprecated [`marquee` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee).  It still works in browsers, but I honestly don't remember if it ever worked in any email clients.

Comment: What about using transform?

Comment: it won't work in [most clients](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/resources/guides/css-animation-in-email-keyframes-transitions-and-sample-code/#one), and if you can only inline css then you won't be able to make it work even for the supported clients.

Comment: [Here you see all email clients that support this](https://www.caniemail.com/search/?s=animation) You can also adapt the search to see what is supported for other ideas you have. gif will work everywhere (where images are allowed) .Otherwise stick to a simple design, this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

The same with the deprecated `marquee` tag:

```html
<div style="display:flex;
  width:600px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: auto;
  background-color:#1892a0;">

  <marquee style="display:flex;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    white-space: nowrap;
    top: 10px;
    left: 0%;
    justify-content:round;
    font-family: 'TriviaSlabBook', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:32px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:white;">

    <span>SPRING BOGO SALE! &nbsp;</span>
    <span>SPRING BOGO SALE! &nbsp;</span>
    <span>SPRING BOGO SALE! &nbsp;</span>
    <span>SPRING BOGO SALE! &nbsp;</span>
  </marquee>
</div>
```

Here's the SVG version:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg width="600mm" height="50mm" viewBox="0 0 600 50" version="1.1" id="svg1" xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape" xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

  <g inkscape:label="marquee" inkscape:groupmode="layer" id="layer1">
    <rect class="cont" id="rect1" width="600" height="50" x="0" y="0" inkscape:label="bg"/>
    <!-- Animate the entire group to create a scrolling effect -->
    <g class="outerCon">
      <text xml:space="preserve" class="textCon" id="text1" inkscape:label="text">
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="translate" from="-600,0" to="-1109,0" dur="5s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
        <tspan y="40" class="text">SPRING BOGO SALE!</tspan>
        <tspan y="40" class="text">SPRING BOGO SALE!</tspan>
        <tspan y="40" class="text">SPRING BOGO SALE!</tspan>
      </text>
    </g>
  </g>

  <style>
    rect {
      fill: #1892a0;
      fill-opacity: 1;
      stroke: none;
      stroke-width: 1.72695;
      font-size: 0;
    }
    .tspan {
      font-family: Arial;
      fill: #ffffff;
    }
    text {
      font-family: 'TriviaSlabBook', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      text-align: center;
      letter-spacing: 0px;
      word-spacing: 0px;
      display: inline;
      fill: #fff;
      fill-opacity: 1;
      stroke: none;
      font-size: 40px;
    }
  </style>

</svg>
```

In this example you can adjust the speed, and there's also no more gap than the given gaps between the `tspan`s.
Bear in mind that you'll have to adjust the `to` attribute according to the width of the text in the `tspan` - if the text content is other than this.

Then, you can save this and embed it as an .svg picture file.

I tested it, and appears in Thunderbird, but online Gmail is blocking it, though maybe if the sender is trusted, and the receiver sets an exception to display it in the mail, it might appear there as well.

For overall support: https://www.caniemail.com/features/image-svg/

Comment: Not an acceptable solution. I need to control speed and (sometimes use ease-in-out) the text can't have a blank gap. It needs to loop infinitely without the blank gap.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Please, take a look!

Answer (score 0):

I think email clients do not support the @keyframes css tag.
Unless someone has a workaround, I'll consider this issue closed.